# Why does sbt report "error: '.' expected but eof found." for an AutoPlugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to create a sbt plugin with new `AutoPlugin` feature, but failed.

All code is here:

**build.sbt**

```
sbtPlugin := true

name := "my-sbt-plugin"

version := "0.1.0"

organization := "test20140913"
```

**project/MySbtPlugin.scala**

```
import sbt._

object MySbtPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("hello task from my plugin")
  }

  import autoImport._

  val helloSetting = hello := println("Hello from my plugin")

  override def projectSettings = Seq(
    helloSetting
  )

}
```

**project/build.scala**

```
import sbt._

object MySbtPluginBuild extends Build {

  lazy val root = project.in(file("."))

  root.enablePlugins(MySbtPlugin)

}
```

When I run `sbt` on it, it reports an error:

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /myplugin/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
/sbttest/myplugin/build.sbt:0: error: '.' expected but eof found.
import _root_.sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, _root_.sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, _root_.sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, _root_.sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, MySbtPlugin
```

**repo**

You can clone it: https://github.com/freewind/my-sbt-plugin, then run `./sbt` to reproduce it

Comment: please try sbt0.13.6

Comment: also it helps to remove build.sbt - seems like problem with parser/code_generator

Comment: With sbt0.13.6, the error is disappeared, but I still can't use this plugin in other projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I fixed the plugin, you can see the updated code here: https://github.com/freewind/my-sbt-plugin

There are several issues in the question:

1. The `project/build.scala` is not needed. The part of `enablePlugins` only need to be added to the projects which use this plugin, should not in the plugin project itself.
2. With `sbt 0.13.5`(I used in the question), the plugin must be inside a package, can't be a top level one. This issues is fixed in `sbt 0.13.6`
3. The plugin can't be enabled automatically, unless we add this line into the plugin:

   ```
   override def trigger = allRequirements
   ```

   Otherwise(or not override `trigger`), we have to add the `enablePlugins` part in the `build.sbt` or `Build.scala` in to the project which use this plugin.
4. Important note: If you created another project to try the plugin locally during development, you need to delete the `target` dirs(e.g. `target/` or `project/target`) before you run `sbt`. Otherwise you will have a lot of strange problems.

Comment: Thank you! Spot on with (2) spared me a lot of grief. As cool as SBT is, weird edge cases like this make the curve quite steep, especially when first trying to use it to solve non-trivial problems.

Answer (score 3):

`Project` in sbt is immutable, i.e. all the methods *transform* it.   Sbt will reflectively find projects you've defined on values.

Basically:

**project/build.scala**

```
import sbt._

object MySbtPluginBuild extends Build {

  lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  // here you're constructing a new project instance which is ignored.
  root.enablePlugins(MySbtPlugin)

}
```

All you have to do is chain together your project DSL and assign the result into the val, which is the only thing sbt pays attention to:

```
import sbt._

object MySbtPluginBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).enablePlugins(MySbtPlugin)
}
```

Comment: I just fixed it as you recommend, but the error is still there